# script class can not be found unity error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm new to unity and c# and after dealing with some compiling errors my script was compiling with just some warnings so i tried to put it into a game object and unity said "can't add script "startscreen" because script class can not be found" i searched about this error and all i found is about matching the class name and the file name but i checked so many times and it matches, after i saw about compiling errors but as i said the console only show warnings and finally i tried to delete all and recreate, i tried reimport all and i tried to change project now i realy don't know what to try, here's one of my 3 scripts maybe there is an error but the error massage appears on every script

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class startscreen : MonoBehaviour
{
   public event EventHandler switchMenu;

   private void ChangeButtonSelected(object sender, EventArgs e){
        buttonStart=gameobject.FindGameObjectWithTag("button").GetComponent<button1>();
        buttonOther=gameobject.FindGameObjectWithTag("button").GetComponent<button2>();
        butonStart.selectChange(e);
        butonOther.selectChange(e); 
   }

    void Start(){
        switchMenu += ChangeButtonSelected;
    }
    void Update(){
        if(input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Left) || input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Right)){
             if(input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Left)){
                 string key = "left";
             }if(input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Right)){
                 string key = "right";
             }
             switchMenu?.invoke(this, EventArgs.key);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I't very hard to solve the issue with the informations provided. I suggest you to recreate the scripts directly from Inspector Window -> Add Component -> Script component and check if it solve the issue.